# VsCode plugin error 'Property 'X' does not exist on type '{}' in Vue 3 template

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am configuring my vue-cli project (composition api with `<script setup>`) to fully support TypeScript. VSCode gives me errors every time when using variables inside template tags.  I am using Vue Language Features (Volar) v0.39.4 plugin.

I tried unsuccessfully:

- add vue-file-import.d.ts
- tsconfig.json edits
- reloading VSCode

Example:

```
//  ../src/views/component-a/Main.vue
<template>
 <div>
  {{string}} // gives VsCode error: Property 'string' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
 </div>
</template>


<script setup lang="ts">
  const string: string = 'wohoo';
</script>
```

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    // "src/**/*.tsx",
    // "tests/**/*.ts",
    // "tests/**/*.tsx"
    "x/**/*.ts",
    "x/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    // "src",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

```
//shims-vue.d.ts
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution: downgraded Volar plugin to older version v0.34.11 (from v0.39.4)